# Do not load time streaming audio on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, streaming

I want to play it on my web audio streaming from a station. Pressing the play by loadstart event message appears LOADING but is removed before it starts playing audio streaming, about 4 or 5 seconds earlier. I wish the event would control the time it is taking the streaming file to load.

Desktop computer the problem does not exist because the audio load instantly, but in Smartphone in the Chrome browser and the S.O. Android this problem is very pronounced and takes about 6 or 7 seconds to load. So I would control this time by some event.

What kind of event could be used for the message LOADING not removed until the audio does not start playing? Thank you.

```
 function AudioStart(){
    audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = "http://listen.XXXX.com/XXXX";

    audio.addEventListener("loadstart", function(){

document.getElementById('title').innerHTML="<span>LOADING...</span>";

;
},false);


audio.addEventListener("loadeddata", function(){

audio.play();

},false);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Listen `oncanplay` instead of `loadeddata` or `oncanplaythrough` if you ant to make sure entire audio is loaded.

*The `loadeddata` event occurs when data for the current frame is loaded, but not enough data to play next frame of the specified audio/video.*

*The `canplay` event occurs when the browser can start playing the specified audio/video (when it has buffered enough to begin)*

*The `canplaythrough` event occurs when the browser estimates it can play through the specified audio/video without having to stop for buffering.*

Try this:

```js
function AudioStart() {
  audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3";

  audio.addEventListener("loadstart", function() {
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "<span>LOADING...</span>";
  }, false);

  audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() { //OR 'oncanplaythrough'
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = "";
    audio.play();
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<h3 id='title'></h3>
<button onclick='AudioStart()'>Start Audio</button>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/01pwyeym/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much Rayon, the problem now is that the sign is not removed LOADING ... it stays put. Should not removed at the beginning of the audio?

Comment: It was the first thing I tried it and it does not work, there must be something wrong Rayon.

It seems that the function stops there. The strange thing is that if he loaded the audio, but does not remove the message in any way LOADING ...

Comment: I have it on localhost, see if I can upload, you could have fun by private? Then the problem if we could edit my initial post.

Comment: The problem is that on my mobile phone does not work, could you try it on your smartphone?